# Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading Shiryaev's Probability Theory, and I am unable to understand the proof of a result concerning the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

He defines the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb{R}^n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the collection $\mathcal{S}$ of all *rectangles*
$$ S = S_1 \times \ldots \times S_n, \quad S_k = (a_k, b_k]. $$

He then claims and proceeds to prove that
$$ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),   $$
where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by the *Borel rectangles*
$$ B = B_1 \times \ldots B_n, \quad B_k \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), $$
i.e.\
$$ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \sigma(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \times \ldots \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) $$

I don't understand the line of reasoning in the proof.

Before continuing, I would like to point out that I found some posts about this on MSE, namely [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069683/proof-about-borel-sigma-algebra-on-mathbbr2) and [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353882/a-clarification-regarding-the-borel-sigma-algebra-on-mathbbr2), both of which provide quite nice arguments for this proof.
However, I would like to understand how the proof in the book works.

Shiryaev only proves it for $n=2$, which clearly suffices by induction.
First off, it is trivial that
$$ \mathcal B(\mathbb{R}^2) \subset \mathcal B(\mathbb{R}) \otimes B(\mathbb{R}), $$
since every rectangle is also a Borel rectangle.
The converse is what confuses me.
He denotes 
$$ \tilde{\mathcal{B}}_1 = \mathcal{B}_1 \times \mathbb{R}, \quad \tilde{\mathcal{B}}_2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathcal{B}_2,  $$
and
$$ \tilde{\mathcal{S}}_1 = \mathcal{S}_1 \times \mathbb{R}, \quad \tilde{\mathcal{S}}_2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathcal{S}_2,  $$
where $\mathcal{S}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{S}_{2}$ are the systems of half-open intervals that form the sides of the rectangles from before. 
He then claims that
for all $B_1 \times B_2 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have
\begin{align}
B_1 \times B_2 = \tilde B_1 \cap \tilde B_2 \in \tilde{\mathcal{B}}_1 \cap \tilde{\mathcal{B}}_2,
\end{align}
where $\tilde B_1 = B_1 \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde B_2 = \mathbb{R} \times B_2$,
which I understand. However, then he proceeds by saying
$$ \tilde{\mathcal{B}}_1 \cap \tilde{\mathcal{B}}_2 \color{red}{=} \sigma(\tilde{\mathcal{S}}_1) \cap \tilde B_2 = \sigma(\tilde{\mathcal{S}}_1 \cap \tilde B_2)
\color{red}{\subset} \sigma(\tilde{\mathcal{S}}_1 \cap \tilde{\mathcal{S}}_2) = \sigma(\mathcal{S}_1 \times \mathcal{S}_2) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2). $$
The steps marked in red are the ones that I cannot wrap my head around. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: On the first mark: do you agree with/understand $\tilde{\mathcal B}_1=\sigma(\tilde{\mathcal S}_1)$?

Comment: @drhab Yes, I can see that being true.

Comment: That solves your first problem, doesn't it?

Comment: @drhab Partially, I still don't see how one obtains the same collection by intersecting by the fixed set $\tilde{B}_2$ on the right hand side, since on the left hand side we are intersecting $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}_1$ with the whole collection $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}_2$? Is this a typo perhaps? **EDIT**: Ah, in any case I could just take $\tilde{B}_2$ instead of $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}_2$ from the start. So yes, that solves the first equality, thanks! What about the second problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I overlooked that on LHS we have a collection and on right a fixed set. Are you sure that on RHS we are dealing with only a fixed set? Looks weird to me.

Comment: @drhab See my edit. If we are not dealing with only a fixed set, then I don't know why the second equality of the chain holds either, so that's not really good!

Comment: It's a typo. The $B$ should be $\mathcal B$. This proof seems overly laborious especially for the $n=2$ case.

Comment: @Matematleta Well in that case I'll just stick with your proof from [1]. You got an upvote from me!

Comment: Thank you. The crux of this is to show that $\left \{ A\times \mathbb R :A\in \mathscr B(\mathbb R)\right \}\subseteq \mathscr B(\mathbb R^{2})$. You can do this by using projections, or just by checking directly, which is what Sirayev is doing I guess.

Comment: @Matematleta What do you think of the way Shirayev defines $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$? I don't like it, and IMV it must be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the usual topology on $\mathbb R^2$ (so that continuous functions are automatically measurable). Following Shirayevs definition the trivial side is proving that $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)\subseteq\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\otimes\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. If the definition that I propose is applied then I should rather call that the non-trivial side.

Comment: @drhab I seem to prefer the definition that starts from the open sets. It feels a bit more natural since this definition can be made in any topological space (right?). Also I've never even seen the notion of a "rectangle" before reading Shiryaev. I guess he didn't want to involve topology into this for some reason.

Comment: @MisterRiemann As you say: every topological space goes along with a Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I think we are on the same line here.