# Prove that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Dynkin system

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The three conditions of a Dynkin system are

1. $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
2. If $A \times B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ then $(A\times B)^c \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
3. If $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ where $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Here $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the real line.

The first condition is obvious.

My attempt for condition 2 so far is we get
$(A\times B)^c = (A \times B^c) \cup (A^c \times B)\cup (A^c \times B^c)$. We know that $(A \times B^c), (A^c \times B), (A^c \times B^c) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ but we need condition 3 or at least closure under finite unions to prove that their union is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Could I get some hints on how conditions 2 and 3 can be proved?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @user10354138 It would be the Cartesian product of all sets in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: That is not how we usually define $\otimes$ of $\sigma$-algebras --- it fails to even contain the unit (circular) disc.  We use $\otimes$ and not $\times$ for a reason.

Comment: Perhaps I've been misunderstanding the notation but this question describes it as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by all Borel rectangles. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061689/borel-sigma-algebra-on-mathbbrn

Comment: Precisely.  You have a $\sigma$-algebra here, which is automatically a d-system.  You have a lot more than just the Cartesian product of all pairs of sets in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Do we know that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is immediately a $\sigma$-algebra though? I feel like it only follows immediately if you know $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ beforehand?

Comment: You *define* it to be a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}):=\sigma(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.  You don't need anything else to prove $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a d-system.  Now if you want to show it is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, it is a easy exercise to show that the open disc is a countable union of open rectangles and the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is generated by rational radius balls centered at rational points.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I thought it followed from its equality to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. The conditions follow immediately with this then.